# change image on iphone screen's wallpaper

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I have a collage image ( many images clubbed together ) , and at the center i have an advertisement banner for example visit the following sample image

[image]

Now, in my application  user can set this image as a wallpaper in iphone screen. now what i want is to keep changing advertisement banner (here is is MC Donald's) inside this image on a regular interval (after setting the image as a wallpaper).

Comment: Not sure if this is possible yet.  You'd have to generate a new image with the new ad and the user would have to manually save it to their photo roll and then make it their wallpaper each time it was updated.  I don't think that's your intention and what user would want to do that.

Comment: no i really don't want to do that , but is it possible that i create a new image with a new add banner and my application would automatically set the next wallpaper.

And another option is to create animated wallpaper on iphone , just like we have animated wallpaper on our desktop or laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the sdk does not provide this possibility.